# Maximize A[i]*B[i] + A[i]*B[j] + A[j]*B[j], i != j, given two unordered lists of positive integers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, maximize

Can you help me with the algorithm:
Given 2 arrays of equal size `a[]` and `b[]` with integer numbers greater or equal to 1.

Find non-equal indices `i` and `j` (`i != j`) such that the value -

`max(a[i]*b[i] + a[i] * b[j] + a[j] * b[j], a[i]*b[i] + a[j] * b[i] + a[j] * b[j])`

will be maximum.

Example:

`a = [1, 9, 6, 6]` and `b = [9, 1, 6, 6].`

Maximum will be at i = 2 and j = 3 (zero-based indexing):
`a[2]*b[2] + a[2]*b[3] + a[3] * b[3] = 6*6+6*6+6*6 = 108`

Is there a way to find i and j in less then quadratic time?
And the same question for finding objective function value in less then quadratic time?

Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned i != j and then in the equation you used a[i] *b[i], in this case a and b have the same index.

Comment: @DataMoguls yes. we take 1 pair of values from a and b at index i, and another at index j. Can you clarify what confuses you?

Comment: Do the arrays only contain positive numbers?

Comment: @MrSmith42 yes, only positive and integers. Will add to the description.

Comment: @LearningMathematics. For example: a = [1, 9, 6, 6] and b = [9, 1, 6, 6].
Do you suggest take i = 0 and j = 1, in this case we will have max(9+9+81, 9 + 9 + 1) = 99, but maximum will be i = 2, and j = 3, max(6*6 + 6*6 + 6*6, 6*6 + 6*6 + 6*6) = 108.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there’s an O(n log n)-time algorithm.

If we look at the function f(x) = max {a[i] b[i] + a[i] x | i},
it traces out a lower (convex) hull. It basically suffices to evaluate
f(b[j]) + a[j] b[j] for every j, with the one sticking point that
we need i ≠ j.

To fix that problem, we turn to an incremental hull algorithm with
amortized O(log n)-time insertions. The canonical algorithm keeps the
hull in sorted order, allowing for O(log n)-time queries. Starting with
an empty hull, for each index i, we query i and then insert i. Do this
once in forward order and once in reverse order, and take the max.

Comment: not sure how we can query for O(log n) time? In order to evaluate max{...}, we will need to do O(n) calculations and do it for each i. Am I right? I don't see how we can improve it.

Comment: @Sergey the easiest way to implement incremental hull is to apply the same random permutation to a and b and maintain the current hull edges in an unbalanced binary search tree, which will be balanced in expectation due to the shuffle. The search tree is ordered left to right, so the query is basically a regular BST lookup. More details in a computational geometry text.

Comment: @David_Eisenstat, sorry, I understand how we can apply convex hull algorithm, I don't understand why it will be (n log n). My reasoning as follows:
1) The speed of Convex Hull is O(k log(k)) where k - number of points.
2) In case of task, total number of points: k =  O(n^2) in worst case, which equals number of line intersections(to be more precise worst case about n*(n-1) / 2)

As result: O(n^2 log(n)) in worst scenario. 

Am i missing smth?

Comment: @Sergey each `a[i] b[i] + a[i] x` is a line on the plane. If we draw a few random straight lines on the coordinate axis, it's easy to see that the best choice for each `x` is the line that's currently on top. This means the segments of the lines that we want trace a convex hull. We want the relevant segments that form the hull arranged so we can query for `x` as `b[j]` efficiently.

Comment: Added Python code that attempts to implement this. It seems to work according to the brute force test at the end. The `i != j` makes it a bit of a pain to implement and debug.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my attempt at implementing [David Eisenstat's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69045263/2034787). I think the `i != j` restriction made this more complicated but either way, I'd welcome suggestions on improving the code. There's a test at the end against brute force.

The construction of the upper envelope for the lines `A[i]*x + A[i]*B[i]` relies on Andrew's monotone chain convex hull algorithm applied to the dual points transformed from the lines.

Python code:

```py
# Upper envelope of lines in the plane

from fractions import Fraction
import collections

def get_dual_point(line):
  return (line[0], -line[1])

def get_primal_point(dual_line):
  return (dual_line[0], -dual_line[1])

def get_line_from_two_points(p1, p2):
  if p1[0] == p2[0]:
    return (float('inf'), 0)

  m = Fraction(p1[1] - p2[1], p1[0] - p2[0])
  b = -m * p1[0] + p1[1]

  return (m, b)

def cross_product(o, a, b):
  return (a[0] - o[0]) * (b[1] - o[1]) - (a[1] - o[1]) * (b[0] - o[0])


# lower_hull has the structure [(dual_point, original_line, leftmost_x, index)]
def get_segment_idx(lower_hull, x):
  lo = 0
  hi = len(lower_hull) - 1

  # Find the index of the first
  # x coordinate greater than x
  while lo < hi:
    mid = lo + (hi - lo + 1) // 2

    if lower_hull[mid][2] <= x:
      lo = mid
    else:
      hi = mid - 1

  return lo


# Assumes we add points in order of increasing x-coordinates
def add_right_to_lower_hull(lower_hull, point):
  while len(lower_hull) > 0 and lower_hull[-1][0][0] == point[0][0] and lower_hull[-1][0][1] > point[0][1]:
    lower_hull.pop()
  while len(lower_hull) > 1 and cross_product(lower_hull[-2][0], lower_hull[-1][0], point[0]) <= 0:
    lower_hull.pop()
  if not lower_hull or lower_hull[-1][0][0] != point[0][0]:
    lower_hull.append(point)
  # Each segment of the lower hull
  # in the dual plane is a line intersection
  # in the primal plane.
  if len(lower_hull) == 1:
    lower_hull[0][2] = -float('inf')
  else:
    line = get_line_from_two_points(lower_hull[-1][0], lower_hull[-2][0])
    lower_hull[-1][2] = get_primal_point(line)[0]

  return lower_hull


# Assumes we add points in order of decreasing x-coordinates
def add_left_to_lower_hull(lower_hull, point):
  while len(lower_hull) > 0 and lower_hull[0][0][0] == point[0][0] and lower_hull[0][0][1] > point[0][1]:
    lower_hull.popleft()
  while len(lower_hull) > 1 and cross_product(lower_hull[1][0], lower_hull[0][0], point[0]) >= 0:
    lower_hull.popleft()
  if not lower_hull or lower_hull[0][0][0] != point[0][0]:
    lower_hull.appendleft(point)
  # Each segment of the lower hull
  # in the dual plane is a line intersection
  # in the primal plane.
  if len(lower_hull) == 1:
    lower_hull[0][2] = -float('inf')
  else:
    line = get_line_from_two_points(lower_hull[0][0], lower_hull[1][0])
    lower_hull[1][2] = get_primal_point(line)[0]

  return lower_hull


# Maximise A[i] * B[i] + A[i] * B[j] + A[j] * B[j]
def f(A, B):
  debug = False

  if debug:
    print("A: %s" % A)
    print("B: %s" % B)

  best = -float('inf')
  best_idxs = ()

  indexed_lines = [((A[i], A[i] * B[i]), i) for i in range(len(A))]

  # Convert to points in the dual plane
  # [dual_point, original_line, leftmost x coordinate added later, original index]
  dual_points = [[get_dual_point(line), line, None, i] for line, i in indexed_lines]

  # Sort points by x coordinate ascending
  sorted_points = sorted(dual_points, key=lambda x: x[0][0])

  if debug:
    print("sorted points")
    print(sorted_points)

  # Build lower hull, left to right
  lower_hull = []

  add_right_to_lower_hull(lower_hull, sorted_points[0])

  for i in range (1, len(sorted_points)):
    # Query the point before inserting it
    # because of the stipulation that i != j
    idx = sorted_points[i][3]
    segment_idx = get_segment_idx(lower_hull, B[idx])
    m, b = lower_hull[segment_idx][1]
    j = lower_hull[segment_idx][3]
    candidate = m * B[idx] + b + A[idx] * B[idx]

    if debug:
      print("segment: %s, idx: %s, B[idx]: %s" % (segment_idx, idx, B[idx]))

    if candidate > best:
      best = candidate
      best_idxs = (idx, j)

    add_right_to_lower_hull(lower_hull, sorted_points[i])
  
  if debug:
    print("lower hull")
    print(lower_hull)

  # Build lower hull, right to left
  lower_hull = collections.deque()

  lower_hull.append(sorted_points[len(sorted_points) - 1])

  for i in range (len(sorted_points) - 2, -1, -1):
    # Query the point before inserting it
    # because of the stipulation that i != j
    idx = sorted_points[i][3]
    segment_idx = get_segment_idx(lower_hull, B[idx])
    m, b = lower_hull[segment_idx][1]
    j = lower_hull[segment_idx][3]
    candidate = m * B[idx] + b + A[idx] * B[idx]

    if debug:
      print("segment: %s, idx: %s, B[idx]: %s" % (segment_idx, idx, B[idx]))

    if candidate > best:
      best = candidate
      best_idxs = (idx, j)

    add_left_to_lower_hull(lower_hull, sorted_points[i])

  if debug:
    print("lower hull")
    print(lower_hull)

  return best, best_idxs


#A = [1, 9, 6, 6]
#B = [9, 1, 6, 6]

#print("")
#print(f(A, B))


# Test

import random

def brute_force(A, B):
  best = -float('inf')
  best_idxs = ()

  for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
      if i != j:
        candidate = A[i] * B[i] + A[i] * B[j] + A[j] * B[j]
        if candidate > best:
          best = candidate
          best_idxs = (i, j)

  return best, best_idxs


num_tests = 500
n = 20
m = 1000

for _ in range(num_tests):
  A = [random.randint(1, m) for i in range(n)]
  B = [random.randint(1, m) for i in range(n)]

  _f = f(A, B)
  _brute = brute_force(A, B)

  if _f[0] != _brute[0]:
    print("Mismatch")
    print(A)
    print(B)
    print(_f, _brute)

print("Done testing.")
```

Comment: Looks like, I don't understand how you convert convex hull for line intersection task to convex hull for points. You use dual plane, but I have no idea about this. Thx, I need some time to understand.

Comment: @Sergey the conversion appeared in some text I read. I cannot find it now but I was googling convex hull for lines, then incremental hull, then upper envelope, I don't remember the exact search terms. Here's another article that might help: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.212.370&rep=rep1&type=pdf